# Single table with many large arrays vs many tables

Tags: mysql, arrays, json, dictionary

I have 200 entities that each contain some data about themselves. Each of the 200 entities also have 3 arrays of dictionaries that will have data appended to them daily. My issue is I could have a single table that has something like this:

```
Entities_Table
    entity1_id(pk) | entity1_name | entity1_data1 | entity1_data2 | entity1_data3 | entity1_array1 | entity1_array2 | entity1_array3 | entity2...
```

The array1-3 will begin small but will grow large with data appended every day. I'll also need to be able to do queries against those arrays like getting the first X or last X sorted by some value in the array. Each array value will be a dictionary with 3 values (timestamp and 2 data points). So in this case they would be JSON objects.

Also, there may be 1-3 new entities created each year, which would mean either creating new tables for those entities or adding columns to the existing table, making it larger still. If I were to create separate tables, I would still have a main table with static data (new rows will be created only the 1-3 times a year that new entities are created):

```
Entities_Table
    entity1_id(pk) | entity1_name | entity1_data1 | entity1_data2 | entity1_data3
```

Then I'd have a separate table for each entities arrays (all 3 arrays can be combined since they share the same timestamp) that will have new rows created daily:

```
Entity1_Array_Data
    timestamp | data1 | data2 | data3 | data4 | ...

Entity2_Array_Data
    timestamp | data1 | data2 | data3 | data4 | ...

...
```

This would result in 201 tables to represent each entities data.

I'm not too familiar with how JSON documents work with MySQL, but if it's more efficient, then maybe a single table to represent this data is still better. I could also split the columns into multiple tables, say tables for 50 entities, that way if a table gets too large, I could create a new one for the next 50 entities, and so on.

Also, queries will only ever be done per entity and getting all data from a single row

Comment: Sounds like you need a nosql database not a relational one.

Comment: if there is no relation use nosql databases like mongoDB. But in normalization many table is better than single table with huge values for your query result time.

Comment: That's what I was thinking as well. Though we may be limited to mysql for now, that definitely seems like the direction we should go in. Thanks!